# Heroku, DNSSimple, and SSL: web app is still not secure

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I'm trying to implement HTTPS on a custom domain for a Heroku application, but it returns an error stating that the connection is not secure - similar to the one seen here [[link]](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/ssl-certificate-herokuapp-error/).

I purchased a certificate from **DNSSimple**. After setting up the SSL endpoint on Heroku,  `heroku certs` returns:

Endpoint: `foo.herokussl.com`
Common Names: `www.mydomain.com, mydomain.com`
Trusted: `True`

On my DNSimple advanced editor for my domain, I have the following ALIAS and CNAME records:

```
ALIAS   mydomain.com        3600        another-name.herokuapp.com  
CNAME   www.mydomain.com    3600        another-name.herokuapp.com
```

I'm not sure why the connection to the custom domain is still not secure. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is in the US region you should be using `foo.herokussl.com` as your ALIAS and CNAME values and not `herokuapp.com` addresses.